# Temporary storage for Azure WebSites

Tags: caching, azure, azure-storage, azure-web-app-service, temporary

I want to cache some cropped images and serve them without calculating them again in a Azure WebSite. When I used the Azure VM I was just storing them at the D drive (temporary drive) but I don't know where to store them now.

I could use the `Path.GetTempPath` but I am not sure if this is the best approach.

Can you suggest me where should I store my Temporary files when I am serving from a Azure WebSite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the processed content on Azure Blob Storage and serve the content from there.

Comment: The Blob Storage is permanent storage and I need something temporary so it can recycle once in a while without having to recycle it myself.

Comment: You could store them in a new container every day, and then "recycle it myself" would just be deleting yesterday's container. If you want fully automatic expiry, then you need a caching solution (like azure redis cache using automatic key expiry, or a CDN where the CDN takes care of expiring stale content). What were you doing to manage expiry when you were using Azure VMs?

Comment: I will implement an expiring caching mechanism at Azure Blob Storage for this scenario.  This is the most safe and cost efficient way for storing Images

Answer (score 4):

Azure Websites also comes with a Temp folder. The path is defined in the environment variable %TEMP%

Comment: This is the same as `Path.GetTempPath`. I don't know how it reacts when it grows bigger in time. What happens when it grows and fill the 90% of the storage? Does it get recycled once in a while or it will stay there until deleted?

Comment: @MenelaosVergis The temp folder is a physical folder on the VM that you're using.  If I remember correctly you can store up to 50GB of data in there and once it fills up you'll get out of storage exceptions.  It comes with a cost though. since the temp folder is on the same physical machine, if the machine goes down or your site moves to another machine for any reason you loose everything that was in the temp folder.  You should accept that you can loose the contents of that folder at any moment (for e.g. if you scale up or down, you'll change machines and loose that data)

Comment: You are right Zain, you should also know that this Temp folder is accessible from all of the sites running at the same VM and this is something that can cause security problems.

Comment: @MenelaosVergis Not true, you can test this for yourself. Create two sites in the same Web Hosting Plan. Change it to Basic mode and scale it to just one instance. Both the sites will be running on the same VM right now. Add some files to one site's temp folder and and see if you can view them from the other site. You won't be able to see them

Answer (score 3):

You can store your images in App_Data folder in the root of your application or you can use Azure CDN for caching.

Comment: By the way I have similar project just for resizing images on the fly, maybe it will be interested for you (https://github.com/T-Alex/ImageProxy) and I use CDN for caching because it cheap and durable.

Answer (score 0):

If what you really want is a cache you can also look into using the Azure Redis Cache.

Comment: This is for cropped images and the price for big storage in Redis Cache would be unbearable, Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

you can use Path.GetTempPath() and Path.GetTempFileName() functions for the temp file name, but you are limited though in terms of space, so if you're doing a 10K save for every request and expect 100,000 requests at a time per server, maybe blob storage is better.

Following sample demonstrate how to save temp file in azure, both Path and Bolb.

Doc is here:https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-store-temp-files-in-d33bbb10
Code click here:https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-blob-dotnet-store-temp-files/archive/master.zip